# Compound variables? Is this the correct term?

Tags: terminology, several-complex-variables

I asked this yesterday in Cross-validated (the statistics equivalent of here) but got few views and no answers.  So I thought that I would ask it here.

I am looking for a term to describe the concept of a multi-characteristic variable. Examples of this are a) vectors - have both magnitude and direction b) Olympic records - have both event (categorical) and measurement - particularly races which have set distances and record times c) cell identifiers - have both row and column d) coordinates - x, y and z, + other coordinate systems

As can be seen, this term may or may not include relationships between the specified dimensions, but the "variable" lacks meaning without all its components.

Whilst "object", borrowed from programming, may be used, this is perhaps too general for the application. I am looking for a term that falls between "object" and "variable", where the relationships between the various elements are easily visualised/understood.

I thought that compound variable may fit the bill. But is that used for a different concept? If so, what would be a better term?

Comment: Why not just "vector"?  A vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a tuple of $n$ real numbers.

Comment: Vector typically implies interval data types.  This is more general than intervals.  However, tuple may be the word that I was looking for. -Tuple: a suffix denoting an "algebraic symbol (for) an entity or set consisting of as many parts or elements".  Thanks Jair. What do others think?

Comment: Tuple could work.  But in the context of machine learning, data is typically encoded into a vector in one way or another, e.g. by one-hot encoding.